# Extracting large zip file onto server while pc is turned off

Tags: cpanel

I've got a zip file of 1,6gb and it takes me forever to extract it on a server. I left it all night long and when i woke up it wasn't finished. There is no way to keep track how much time is left on extracting a file and how much percantage is done so i'm not sure if the whole thing works properly. Is there a way to exctract that file using File manager in Cpanel so that it can be done while the pc is off and maybe to note me on an email when it's done. I basically need to copy a webshop from live server to developers server and am just loosing too much time on that. So if anyone has a better idea how to extract it please feel free to suggest it.

P.S. Deleting of those files that did extract takes forever too

P.P.S. I'm a linux/SystemAdmin

Answer (score 0):

If it's all about copying files from one server to another - why not just use rsync and avoid archiving?
I mean, if extraction is a pain - remove it from the equation :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good ideato use the cPanel File Manager for this task, as the server will probably kill the extract process if it takes too long.

The best way to go about this would be via SSH, while logged in as root. If you need to switch off your computer, you should run it in screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `unzipper.php` which you can get from github.

It will require you to upload your file and `unzipper.php` too. Then run `wwww.yourdomain.con/unzipper.php`